# 1/p in p-adic number system?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

to expand $1/p$, I tried first letting $1/p = a+b*p+c*p^2+d*p^3+...$ and it is $1=a*p+b*p^2+...$ but I guess there's no way to make the equality hold.

it's somewhat similar to dividing by 0. is it possible? I'm new to p-adic theory, everything looks just confusing.

Comment: $1/p$ is in $\mathbb Q_p$, not in $\mathbb Z_p$. You are trying to find a representation in $\mathbb Z_p$, which isn't possible.

Comment: To expand on @ThomasAndrews, you are _actually_ looking for $0.1_p$, which is allowed in $\Bbb Q_p$ (all finite decimal expansions are allowed there).

Comment: Be careful with "decimal" - it implies base $10$. @Arthur

Comment: so can i just treat it like $p^{-1}$? and no nonnegative power expansion about it?

Comment: Treat it "like" $p^{-1}$? It is $p^{-1}$. @awvt

Comment: To put it more precise, every element in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is of the form $\sum_{i\geq n} a_i p^i$ where $n$ is some negative integer (well can be non-negative but that would ensure the element is in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: The invertible elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are those that are not divisible by $p$.

Comment: Or, every non-zero element of $\mathbb Q_p$ can be written uniquely as $p^n(a_0+a_1p+a_2p^2+\dots)$ where $n$ is an integer, $0\leq a_i\leq p-1$ and $a_0\neq 0$. Alternatively, every non-zero element of $\mathbb Q_p$ can be written as $p^nu$ where $u$ is a unit of $\mathbb Z_p$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So I should call it a "$p$-mal expansion"? I personally prefer using the words decimal and digits even though it's not base $10$, but in anything longer than a comment I would probably point it out explicitly.

Comment: Feel free to continue being wrong for brevity's sake. @Arthur I prefer "base $p$" to $p$-mal.

Answer (score 4):

My own convention is to write $p$-adic numbers as $p$-ary expansions extending (potentially) infinitely to the left, and only finitely to the right of the radix point, which I like to write as a semicolon. So, $5$-adically, five is $10;$, twenty-eight is $103;$, and one twenty-fifth is $0;01$. For infinite expansions, $-1=\dots4444;$ and one tenth is $\dots2222;3\>$. In particular, $1/p$ will always have the expansion $0;1$, just as one tenth in decimal is $0.1$

Answer (score 1):

The elements of $\mathbf Q_p$ are kinds of *Laurent series* in $p$:
$$\sum_{k\ge k_0}a_k\mkern1.5mu p^k,\quad(k_0\in \mathbf Z)$$
the coefficients $a_k$ being subject to the condition $\;0\le a_k<p$. Hence $\dfrac 1p$ is but… $\dfrac 1p$.

Comment: Actually, it is $\sum_{k\leq k_0}$ or $\sum_{k\geq k_0} a_kp^k$. It is a Laurent series in $p$, not $1/p$. (Well, Laurent series are double-sided, I suppose.)

Comment: You're right, I messed up in my notations. Thanks for pointing it! It's corrected now. That said, for me, a Laurent series  is defined ‘ from left to right’, so to say.

Comment: No, you didn't fix the $\sum$ notation part of your answer.

Comment: Forgot that part of the formula… Thanks again.

Comment: I'd also avoid the term Laurent series, since (1) they are implicitly infinite on both sides, (2) they are a proper name that the questioner might or might not know (3) while there is a sense in which it is technically true, by some definition of "Laurent series," the standard usage is in complex analysis. If one were to go to the Wikipedia page to find out what the term means, one will likely be very confused as to its application here.

Comment: My usage of this term was purely metaphoric. It is used that way in the domain of formal power series and also, as far far as <I know, in $p$-adic analysis. To avoid any ambiguity, I modified my wording.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there exists an $\alpha$ such that $\alpha = \frac{1}{p}$, then $\alpha p = 1$. However, multiplying any integer in $\mathbb Z_p$ and $p$ gives an integer ending in $0$, which is a contradiction. So $\frac{1}{p}$ does not exist in $\mathbb Z_p$.